# hide android keyboard on focus

Tags: html, web-applications, keyboard, focus

I have a problem with my webapp. 
Is there a way to hide the android keyboard on text input focus without losing the focus on the input?
Focus on page load works fine, because the field is focused and no keyboard is shown. I want the same behavior after re-focus on input.
Thank You

Comment: Showing us how you do it already would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give keyboard customizing apps a try...might work. I personally prefer Redraw Keyboard, but there are many out there to choose from.